# CodeIgniter passing model data to the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model method which returns time and view to pass the data. But when I pass the data I get **Undefined variable** error message.

```
$this->load->model('Driver_model');
$result = $this->Driver_model->get_shift_data($id);
```

This is the method calling and if I use **var_dump($result)**. I get following result.

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[26]
      public 'start_time' => string '2016-01-22 05:32:42' (length=19)
```

But if I send the $result to the view, I get error.

```
$this->load->view('driver/report_view.php', $result);
```

My question is, how it possible to work in controller if I don't load the view. But if I send the data, it doesn't identify the variable.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: driver/report_view.php

Line Number: 52

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\cabs\application\views\driver\report_view.php
Line: 52
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\cabs\application\controllers\Driver.php
Line: 44
Function: view

File: C:\wamp\www\cabs\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

I have tested it using var_dump($result) in view as well.

```
      <div class="panel-body">
Line 52    <?php var_dump($result); ?>                              
        <form>
```

Comment: Show us how you use the variables in the View script. That is where the error is being reported so that is the code we need to see

Comment: I just use it as var_dump($result)

Comment: See the referenced duplicate for yrou answer

Comment: Follow thw duplicate link aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass a simple variable `$result` in load view function for view.

You need to create an associative array for sending data to view from controller. You can use as:

```
$this->load->model('Driver_model'); $data['result'] = $this->Driver_model->get_shift_data($id);
```

Now send `$data` array to your view as:

```
$this->load->view('driver/report_view.php', $data);
```

Now you can use `var_dump()` in view file as:

```
<?php var_dump($result); ?>
```

**Note that** if you want to send any other data from controller to view you can follow the same example.

**For more explanation see this example:**

```
$data['result'] = 1;
$data['result2'] = 2;
$data['result3'] = 3;

$this->load->view('yourview', $data);
```

**In view you can get data as:**

```
echo $result; // 1
echo $result2; // 2
echo $result3; // 3
```

Comment: When I do it your way I get A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @isuru bcoz u r using array as a string. Use Print_r()  and this is not my way.. its codeginitor standard way